# Graphite label aliases via dashboard JSON

Tags: json, graphite

I have a file like this:

```
[
  {
    "target": [
      "server.access-log-parser.gauge.registration_iOS",
      "server.access-log-parser.gauge.registration_BB",
      "server.access-log-parser.gauge.registration_AND",
      "server.gauge.registration"
    ],
    "title": "Registration"
  }
]
```

I would like the labels to be "iOS", "Blackberry", "Android", and "Total". I believe there is some sort of alias function in graphite, but I cannot find and documentation for what the dashboard JSON file should look like to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
[
  {
    "target": [
      "alias(server.access-log-parser.gauge.registration_iOS,'iOS')",
      "alias(server.access-log-parser.gauge.registration_BB,'Blackberry')",
      "alias(server.access-log-parser.gauge.registration_AND,'Android')",
      "alias(server.gauge.registration,'Total')"
    ],
    "title": "Registration"
  }
]
```